# Adding horizontal labeled horizontal arrows in multicol environment

Tags: tables, spacing, arrows

I have attached a picture of what I am attempting to create. The issue is, when trying to do this in Latex, I am messing up my spacing.

I want to add a bold black arrow between the top two tables and another bold black arrow between the bottom two tables. I would also like to label these arrows with specific text.

Is there some way to import graphics without ruining the spacing, or is there a way to create these arrows with text inside of Latex?

Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,hhline}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
% Set theme to UNA2
\usetheme{UNA2}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small #1}}
\newcommand{\divides}{\bigm|}
\newcommand{\ndivides}{%
\mathrel{\mkern.5mu % small adjustment
% superimpose \nmid to \big|
\ooalign{\hidewidth$\big|$\hidewidth\cr$\nmid$\cr}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Quasigroups and the Sudoku Property}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CC}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{\phantom{1}} \\% Empty line
\hline
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline
2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
\hhline{|=|=#=|=|}
3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\hline
4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 2 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
\hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
\small 3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} \\
\begin{tabular}{c} A $4\times4$ table with \\ $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c} A labeled $4\times4$ table \\ with $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks
\end{tabular} \\[2\normalbaselineskip]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
\small 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} \\
\begin{tabular}{c} A Cayley Table representing \\ a Quasigroup \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c} The same Quasigroup with \\ the Sudoku property \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,hhline}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

% Set theme to UNA2
%\usetheme{UNA2}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small #1}}
\newcommand{\divides}{\bigm|}
\newcommand{\ndivides}{%
\mathrel{\mkern.5mu % small adjustment
% superimpose \nmid to \big|
\ooalign{\hidewidth$\big|$\hidewidth\cr$\nmid$\cr}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Quasigroups and the Sudoku Property}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CC}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{\phantom{1}} \\% Empty line
\hline
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline
2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \tikzmark{starta}\\
\hhline{|=|=#=|=|}
3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\hline
4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small \tikzmark{enda}2 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
\hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
\small 3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} \\
\begin{tabular}{c} A $4\times4$ table with \\ $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c} A labeled $4\times4$ table \\ with $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks
\end{tabular} \\[2\normalbaselineskip]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \tikzmark{startb} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small \tikzmark{endb}2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
\small 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} \\
\begin{tabular}{c} A Cayley Table representing \\ a Quasigroup \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c} The same Quasigroup with \\ the Sudoku property \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,>=latex]
\draw[->,line width=2pt]
  ([xshift=15pt,yshift=-0.4\baselineskip]pic cs:starta) -- node[above,align=center] {\strut Viewing as \\ Algebra\strut}
  ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-0.4\baselineskip]{{pic cs:enda}|-{pic cs:starta}});
\draw[->,line width=2pt]
  ([xshift=15pt,yshift=-0.35\baselineskip]pic cs:startb) -- node[above,align=center] {\strut Applying \\ Sudoku\strut}
  ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-0.35\baselineskip]{{pic cs:endb}|-{pic cs:startb}});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code needs two or three runs to stabilize.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is nigh perfect. Now I just need to find a way to add some color to this slide so that it isn't so bland.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,hhline}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
% Set theme to UNA2
\usetheme{UNA2}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small #1}}
\newcommand{\divides}{\bigm|}
\newcommand{\ndivides}{%
\mathrel{\mkern.5mu % small adjustment
% superimpose \nmid to \big|
\ooalign{\hidewidth$\big|$\hidewidth\cr$\nmid$\cr}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Quasigroups and the Sudoku Property}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CcC}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{\phantom{1}} \\% Empty line
\hline
1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline
2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
\hhline{|=|=#=|=|}
3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\hline
4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Viewing as\\
Algebra\\[2ex]
\resizebox{1cm}{.6cm}{$\rightarrow$}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 2 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
\hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
\small 3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} \\
\begin{tabular}{c} A $4\times4$ table with \\ $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks \end{tabular} &
&
\begin{tabular}{c} A labeled $4\times4$ table \\ with $2\times2$ Sudoku blocks
\end{tabular} \\[2\normalbaselineskip]%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
Applying\\
Sudoko\\[2ex]
\resizebox{1cm}{.6cm}{$\rightarrow$}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c||c|c|}
\mc{} & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
\hhline{~|=|=#=|=|}
\small 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{2-5}
\small 4 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabular} \\
\begin{tabular}{c} A Cayley Table representing \\ a Quasigroup \end{tabular} &&
\begin{tabular}{c} The same Quasigroup with \\ the Sudoku property \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I prefer the way the code above looks aesthetically, but I appreciate the effort put into this and certainly will keep this for future reference.

Comment: @JohnC oh no:-) Gonzalo and I are having [a little race](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) and this isn't helping:-)